# How can i create multiple objects in one request ? In which each objects have file field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postman, filefield

I'm trying to create multiple documents objects, when i send request without file filed it create multiple objects, but i don't know how to send multiple objects with **filefiled** from 'form-data' of postman or from raw data in json format. Please suggest me what can i do for this.

My Document Model is:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeInfo, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    document = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='passport')
    date_added = models.DateField()
    valid_until = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    detail = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to='attachments', null=True, blank=True)
```

for this my view is :

```
class DocumentAPICreateView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = DocumentSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many = True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            self.perform_create(serializer)            
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            response = create_response(True,data = serializer.data)        
            return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
        else:
            response =  create_response(False, err_name = serializer._errors)
            return Response(response, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

when i send data without attachment it works like this:

```
[{

    "employee":38,
    "document":"Trial2",
    "date_added":"2019-12-10"
},
{

    "employee":38,
    "document":"Trial3",
    "date_added":"2019-12-10"
}]
```

Serializer for this is:

```
class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = '__all__'
```

How can i send objects list with attachment field?

Comment: Could you post your DocumentSerializer too

Comment: @Philip i post serializer for this.

Comment: I think that it's not good idea, to upload several file in one request, create another api for this, when you choose file upload it, and just send file id or path, in my opinion it will be good